# jFormer: Checkboxes and Address

Tags: php, jformer

I've implemented checkboxes into my jFormer form. What returns in the email is "array" and not the value that is set.

```
// Add components to the form
$multipleChoiceComponentForm->addJFormComponentArray(array(
    new JFormComponentMultipleChoice('brochure', 'Multiple choice checkboxes:',
        array(
            array('label' => 'Send Me a brochure', 'value' => 'Yes'),
        ),
        array()
    ),
```

I cannot figure out why its returning "Array" in the email

...the lack of detailed documentation is also not helping. I tried contacting the guy working on the github stuff for jformer, but no answer.

Also, whenever I add

```
new JFormComponentAddress('currentaddress', 'Current Address:', array(
                    'validationOptions' => array(),
                )),
```

the email never process...nor does it give an error...the button just says "processing"

anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

The Docs on jFormer are up at

http://www.jformer.com/documentation/

in jFormer, if the multiplechoice component is of the type 'checkbox' it always returns an array, if you have a single checkbox, try using the key

```
$formValues->brochure[0]
```

for the jFormComponentAddress, try just submitting it without the validations options.